# Is there a way to get form requests from a html form post from the past?

Tags: php, html, forms, post, get

So this is a pretty weird topic, but lets just say I made a big mistake while building a site. There is an application form on my website and people basically fill up the form and their entry gets saved in the database. Now how it is supposed to work is that the form is supposed to post to a page that catches the form fields and stores it in the database. However, I forgot to put the file under action. So basically the form has been posting to itself. Bummer. So based on analytics there were about 100 applicants on my site on that day which means that about 100 applicants are lost as the form was posted to just the page itself and not to the page that was supposed to catch form fields.

So is there a way, any way to get those applicants back?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

The only book I can think of that could possibly help is this: [http://www.amazon.com/Build-Time-Machine-Paul-Davies/dp/0142001864](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0142001864)

Comment: LOL! That is too much... love the answer!

Answer (score 6):

I hate to have to say it, but NO.
Unless you had the form input being recorded in a database, logfile, or other persistent storage, it's lost.

Answer (score 3):

No.

You did not store the data, so it is gone.

Comment: Aren't you the captain of a romulan vessle?

Comment: You should sue Gene Roddenberry for stealing your name and using in a few episodes.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are using I would check the logs.  I'm not 100% on this but you maybe able to see some errors in there.

If not I think you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

In some pretty weird cases you can find some data in your server access log file.

It doesnt hurt to check.

Comment: Not `POST` data. `GET` data you could retrieve through access logs.